# Calculate electricity generation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, fluid-statics

A friend of mine stays near a water stream and wanted help to use its water. The height up to which the water could be raised using the water flow is 12ft. How much electricity can it produce?
Is it at least enough to power half the house?

Comment: How much water per second will be falling 12 feet? If he has some high ground, do a search for "hydraulic ram". You can pump for free to a higher holding tank or pond for on-demand power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency of large hydroelectric generators can be very high - up to 95% in ideal cases - however the efficiency of small installations is a lot lower and in particular it's hard to get efficient electricity generation if the flow rate is low, which is likely to be the case for your friend.

But lets see what the potential is. You don't say what the water flow rate is, so let's just call it $F$ kg/sec. 12 feet is about 3.7m so the power is:

$$ P = Fgh \approx 36F \space\text{Watts} $$

Let's guesstimate the efficiency of electricity generation at 10%, then the electrical power your friend can generate is:

$$ P \approx 3.6F \space\text{Watts} $$

I would guess most houses use a few kW of electricity. If we take 1kW and work out what flow rate is needed to produce this we get:

$$ F \approx \frac{P}{3.6} \approx 280 \text{kg}/\text{sec} \approx 0.28 \text{m}^3/\text{sec} $$

I would guess this flow rate is more than the typical stream, but it's not all that great.

Comment: FWIW, I found a worked example which suggested a small stream w/ cross-sectional area of about 0.2 $m^3$ had a flow rate around 0.22 .

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.Talking about efficiency the jet pipes and pelton  turbines give near 90 percent ,the shape of the turbine wings are made such .....................  I am curious to know if we could generate electricity by using the force of Heavy iron blocks in free fall. If its possible how much energy can a block of iron weighing 1000kg produce if thrown from height of 60m from ground and if possible what mechanism can we use ....just curious :D.

Comment: I am if knowledge ofcourse we cannot take the iron block again back to the height just for the fun of knowing the possibility.

Comment: @user7063: the potential energy change for any object of mass $m$ falling through a height $h$ is given by $\Delta U = mgh$. How much of this potential energy change can be extracted is down to engineering.

Comment: @JohnRennie I am not a physics person.I lately got interested in mechanics and out of curiosity after seeing how water can be used I would like to know how heavy objects can be used .Could I get some help by giving me a blueprint of it .The google search cant help me much.  Thanks